# How to compare two text files in power-shell and send the differences to an email

Tags: powershell

I have 2 text files that contains a list of SQL function names. I want to be able to compare a list in $A and $B. I then want a list of the SQL function names which are in $B and not in $A i.e. list $C to be send as an attachment to an email address.

Here is my code:

```
   $A = "c:\ReferenceFunctions.txt"
   $B = "c:\GeneratedFunctions.txt"
   $C = "c:\FileWithDifferences.txt"


    $fromaddress = "noreply@xyz"
    $toaddress = "123@hhh"
    $bccaddress = "3333@nnn.com"
    $login = "yourlogin"
    $password = "password" | Convertto-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $smtpserver = "gggg.com" 
    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpserver, 800)
    $smtp.EnableSsl = $true
    $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($login, 
    $password);
    $body = "see attached "
    $Subject = "checking differences"
    $message = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $message.From = $fromaddress
    $message.To.Add($toaddress)
    #$message.CC.Add($CCaddress)
    $message.Bcc.Add($bccaddress)
    $message.IsBodyHtml = $True
    $message.Subject = $Subject

    $message.body = $body
    $message.Priority = [System.Net.Mail.MailPriority]::High

Compare-object (Get-Content $A) (Get-Content $B) | Out-File  $C

#Attach the eported file with differences
$attachment = $C
$attach = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachment)
$message.Attachments.Add($attach)

IF (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content $A) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content $B)){


    $smtp.Send($message);
}
```

Variable $A has information as below:

```
fn_StatementEndOfMonth                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
fn_Performance_Sql                                                                                                                                                                                     
fn_DailyReturns
```

Variable $B has the following info:

```
fn_Performance_Sql                                                                                                                                                                                     
fn_DailyReturns 
fn_SQLPerfomance_Monitor
```

$C Should then contain

```
fn_SQLPerfomance_Monitor
```

The problem with this code is that, it is sending an attachment with all the SQL Function names in both file $A and $B instead of the difference. I can't seem to figure out where am going wrong. Any one who can assist please? Been trying to figure out the whole day but no luck.

Comment: While this is better than a lot of questions - I still wouldn't call it an MCVE. If you monitor the variables through the script, where does the problem occur? If you set the variables inline using a very simple example, does the problem still occur? I can't replicate your issue since I have no idea what $A and $B are.

Comment: @JacobColvin $A and $B are two variables that contain names of SQL functions. Not sure what you mean by using a simple example? Also, monitoring the variables through the script - what do you mean?

Comment: Providing some excerpts from your reference and difference files, along with the expected and actual output, might help. I tried it on my own, but I don't know what your input looks like and what you're expecting to see.

Comment: @Immortal I mean narrowing down exactly where the issue is, then providing us all the needed information to replicate just that issue. As it is, there's a lot of extra code here and I can't even replicate the issue since it somewhat depends on the exact structure of $a and $b

Comment: @DanWilson I have added everything you need I suppose? Please check the question again?

Comment: @JacobColvin I have added the missing information. Can you read the question again and see if you can reproduce?

Comment: Did you try `Get-Content $C` ?

Comment: @JosefZ The content in $C is wrong because it includes both contents from $A and $B. This is not helping me

Comment: Pay your attention to  comprehensive [@mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50512478/3439404)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you actually want to do the exact opposite of compare-object. To get exactly what you said you needed in $C (I'm not sure why 'fn_StatementEndOfMonth' shouldn't be there as well), you can do the following:

```
$a = 'fn_StatementEndOfMonth
fn_Performance_Sql
fn_DailyReturns' -split '[\r\n]'

$b = 'fn_Performance_Sql
fn_DailyReturns
fn_SQLPerfomance_Monitor' -split '[\r\n]'

$c = $b | % { if($_ -notin $a){$_} }

$c
```

> fn_SQLPerfomance_Monitor

Comment: `$c = $b | Where-Object { $_ -notin $a }` or using `?` alias `$c = $b | ? { $_ -notin $a }` instead of `Foreach-Object` (alias `%`).

Comment: The OP wants the lines of `$B` that aren't also in `$A` (the lines unique to `$B`), which is only `fn_SQLPerfomance_Monitor` with the sample input; `Compare-Object` can definitely do that, but you need to filter the output objects by `.SideIndicator`. For small collections, however, your approach may be faster (though you should use the `Where-Object` form that @JosefZ recommends).

Comment: @JosefZ @ these function names are on text files and with your method, how am I going to deal with this? The text files gets generated in another process so I wont know how many names in that file.

Comment: @Jacob if the information is on text files, how is your method going to work? Sometimes variable $b might be generated with 500 functions in it and how is it going to work?

Comment: @Immortal Of course, the described method works for _objects_ `$a` and `$b` already fetched from files. To compare _files_, use `(Get-Content $A)` and `(Get-Content $B)` instead of `$a` and `$b`, respectively.

Comment: @JosefZ $c is still having wrong info. See the changes I made:

$dir = "C:\SQL"

$a = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | where-object {$_.name -like "*BenchMarkSQLFunctions*"  } 
Write-Output "The first file name is $a"

$b = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | where-object {$_.name -like "*GeneratedFunctions*"} 
Write-Output "The Second file name is $b"

#$c = (get-content $b) | % { if($_ -notin (get-content $a)){$_} }

$c = (get-content $b) | ? { $_ -notin (get-content $a) }

$c | Out-File c:\Test.txt

Also want to find out if the -split '[\r\n]' is still required when using get-content ?

Answer (score 1):

You must **filter the difference objects that `Compare-Object` outputs by their `.SideIndicator` property** in order to only get the **items that are *unique to a given side*** (PSv3+ syntax):

```
Compare-Object (Get-Content $A) (Get-Content $B) -PassThru | 
  Where-Object Sideindicator -eq '=>' | 
    Out-File $C
```

- `Where-Object Sideindicator -eq '=>'` outputs only those *difference objects* representing item that are unique to the *right* side (i.e., the *second* argument, the lines of file `$B` in this case).

  - A difference object is a `[pscustomobject]` instance that represents a single difference between the input collections. It has two properties:

    - `.SideIndicator` contains an arrow (string) that points toward the side that the input object at hand is unique to: `<=` or `=>`; if you use the `-IncludeEqual` switch, objects present in *both* collections are represented with `==`
    - `.InputObject` represent the input object at hand.
- `-PassThru` results in `Compare-Object` outputting the input objects *themselves* rather than the usual difference objects:

  - This enables you to send *strings* to the output file; without `-PassThru`, `Out-File` would write the difference objects as a whole, resulting in a table representation; you'd have to access the `.InputObject` property in order to get the string only.
  - However, a `.SideIndicator` property is still present, because PowerShell adds a `NoteProperty` member with that name to each object, so the `Where-Object` filter still works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing -PassThru switch on the Compare-Object command:

```
$A = Get-Content 'C:\temp\test1.txt'
$B = Get-Content 'C:\temp\test2.txt'
$C = 'c:\temp\diff.txt'

Compare-Object $A $B -PassThru | Out-File -FilePath $C
```

Comment: `-PassThru` is helpful in that sends the differences as _strings_ to the output file, but by itself it doesn't satisfy the OP's requirement that only the lines _unique to `$B`_ be output.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet shows how `Compare-Object` cmdlet works, and importance of `SideIndicator` property:

```
$a = @'
fn_StatementEndOfMonth
fn_Performance_Sql
fn_DailyReturns
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine               ### ReferenceFunctions
$b = @'
fn_Performance_Sql
fn_DailyReturns
fn_SQLPerfomance_Monitor
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine               ### GeneratedFunctions

[environment]::NewLine                         ### for better output readability
'Compare-Object $a $b'
Compare-Object $a $b
[environment]::NewLine
'Compare-Object $a $b | ? SideIndicator -ne ''<='''
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b| 
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -ne '<=' }
[environment]::NewLine
'Compare-Object $a $b | ? SideIndicator -ne ''=>'''
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b | 
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -ne '=>' }
[environment]::NewLine
'Compare-Object $a $b -PassThru'
Compare-Object $a $b -PassThru
[environment]::NewLine
'Compare-Object $a $b -PassThru | ? SideIndicator -ne ''<='''
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b -PassThru | 
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -ne '<=' }
[environment]::NewLine
'Compare-Object $a $b -PassThru | ? SideIndicator -ne ''=>'''
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b -PassThru | 
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -ne '=>' }
```

**Output**:

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SO\50510142.ps1

Compare-Object $a $b

InputObject              SideIndicator
-----------              -------------
fn_SQLPerfomance_Monitor =>           
fn_StatementEndOfMonth   <=           

Compare-Object $a $b | ? SideIndicator -ne '<='
fn_SQLPerfomance_Monitor =>           

Compare-Object $a $b | ? SideIndicator -ne '=>'
fn_StatementEndOfMonth   <=           

Compare-Object $a $b -PassThru
fn_SQLPerfomance_Monitor
fn_StatementEndOfMonth

Compare-Object $a $b -PassThru | ? SideIndicator -ne '<='
fn_SQLPerfomance_Monitor

Compare-Object $a $b -PassThru | ? SideIndicator -ne '=>'
fn_StatementEndOfMonth
```

For those confused about `Compare-Object` output:

```
$x = Compare-Object $a $b
$x[0].Gettype()
$y = Compare-Object $a $b -PassThru
$y[0].Gettype()
```

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType            
-------- -------- ----                                     --------            
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object       
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Above is valid despite of [documentation (wrongly) says](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=821751)

> **Outputs**
>
> None, or the objects that are different.
>
> When you use the `PassThru` parameter, `Compare-Object` returns the
>   objects that differed. Otherwise, this cmdlet <strike>does not
>   generate any output</strike>.